# Database changes not reflecting in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have created a staging WordPress site with relative paths (URLs). Now, I have to make relative paths on my original WordPress site. I export the database of my staging site and import this database on my original WordPress site. But I cannot see any changes, the absolute paths have not changed to relative paths. Please help.

Comment: have you changed site url and home url in settings->general

Comment: Yes I have changed the urls